# Non-shortest path traces

Tags: pcb-design

Inside a Nintendo Switch I spotted some traces that take a meandering path to the RAM chips.

[image]

What are the benefits of designing it this way, instead of taking the shortest path?

Answer (score 1):

Timing!

The timing on many very fast chips is so critical that the length of all copper traces should ideally be the same. The traces which have no "meandering" are longer underneath the chips, where you can not see that.